# .htaccess php query strings

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is a problem with page redirection in an .htaccess ile, when the pages are idenified by a dynamic PHP string.

I'm not sure anyone can help me with this. It may be an insoluble problem.

I have just moved a client to a new Web site, in which properties for sale are in one subfolder, and properties for rent in another. (On the old site, they were all in the top folder.)

The pages are identified like this:

```
show-property.php?prop=[number]
```

If all properties were going to the same sub-folder, one rule would cover all. But I have to send some properties to the rentals sub-folder, and others to the sales sub-folder, depending on the specific number.

There are 60 active sales properties and 77 active rentals properties.

So I put into the .htaccess file on the old site 137 individual rules, like these:

```
Redirect 301 /show-property.php?prop=100 https://[new-domain]/**rentals**/show-property.php?prop=100

Redirect 301 /show-property.php?prop=101 https://new-domain]/**sales**/show-property.php?prop=101
```

Not surprisingly, none of them works.

With 137 distinct pages, and 2 different destinations, can this problem be solved?

Comment: Apart from these 137 rules, what more do you have in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: Another 27 specific Redirect 301s. These are all working, including one which reads 

    Redirect 301 /holiday-villas.php?sleeps=4 https://[new-domain]/rentals/holiday-villas.php?sleeps=4

This works! So it doesn't look like a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just classify them by `query string` like this :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^prop\=100$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/rentals/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^prop\=101$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/sales/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

**$1**  will match `URI` in old site and **QSA** flag will let query string to appended in new location .

Comment: Well, I'll try this, and let you know if it works. But if it is necessary, how come a rule like
    Redirect 301 /holiday-villas.php?sleeps=4 https://[new-domain]/rentals/holiday-villas.php?sleeps=4 
already works?

Comment: @MichaelScannell that is another rule should be added if you want , becasue the previous rules for specific directories but i could combine what you want to redirect to rentals together , let me know all what you need to give full solution

Comment: I have now tried this rule, and it is working for the first 5 rentals properties and the first 5 sales properties that I have entered. You have solved my problem: brilliant! and thank you very much. (Just 127 property pages to go …)

Comment: glad to help , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a RewriteCondition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/show-property.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} prop=100
RewriteRule (.*) https://[new-domain]/rentals/show-property.php?prop=100 [R=301,L]
```

If there is a way to tell the target from the prop id, you could simplify it, but I doubt this is true in your case.

Comment: That would just send all the properties to the rentals sub-folder. That is obviously not a solution - but I accept there may not be one.

Comment: You had to repeat that for all 137 links of course and change rentals to sales when appropriate, of course. I thought, you would figure that out. I just wanted to show the proper redirect.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. In the meantime Mohammed came up with much the same solution, with slightly different syntax, and I have successfully implemented his solution. I should add that I am not a beginner. I have a copy of the Apache Cookbook from the last century, and I have been creating .htaccess files for at least 15 years. And I was trying to avoid mixing Apache modules. I just wasn't smart enough to think of the solution which you and Mohammed came up with. Thanks again.